# Problem working with selenium on protonmail.com

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to create email  on protonmail.com with selenium
But I can not go beyond the sign up page
i can not find username field and send text to it.
Why??what is  the problem ??
And what is the solution?

my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from random import randint
#setuser=set()
#def randomuser():
#    name='ahmad'
#    num=randint(10000,999999)
#    return f'{name}{num}{name[:randint(0,5)]}'

d=webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://protonmail.com/signup')
WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signup-plans"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/i[1]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(d, 4).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="freePlan"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys('12345678')
WebDriverWait(d, 4).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="repeat-password"]'))).send_keys('12345678')

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    d.find_element_by_css_selector('#username').send_keys('username')
    d.find_element_by_css_selector('#username').submit()
        
except:
    WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(d.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe')))
    user=d.find_element_by_xpath('//body[@class="color-norm bg-norm sign-layout-container"]//*[@id="username"]')
    user.send_keys('username')
    user.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
    user.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username field is inside an iframe.
To access it you have to switch to that iframe first.
Also, `username` is not unique id value.
Also, you need not to define `wait` object each time.
The following should fix your code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signup-plans"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/i[1]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="freePlan"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys('12345678')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="repeat-password"]'))).send_keys('12345678')
d.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
d.find_element_by_xpath("//body[contains(@class,'color-norm')]//input[@id='username']").send_keys('username')
d.find_element_by_xpath("//body[contains(@class,'color-norm')]//input[@id='username']").submit()
```

**UPD**
Please keep in mind, that after switching to iframe, in order to access elements out of that iframe you will have to switch back to the nornal content with

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I just not sure what should be used here in order to submit the form `.submit()` or `.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` did not debug that

Comment: Thankful
It works but when it fills the form
Finally gives this error:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
 And it does not go to the next page

Comment: What element it fails to locate?

Comment: username.submit()

Comment: Do you still using the try-except form as in the question?